# When a URL ends in a slash, does that mean they're using an index file?

Tags: html, url, web, navigation

My spider sense tells me that they're not using a folder with an index file for each page, [like apple's for example](http://www.apple.com/iphone/) where http://www.apple.com/iphone/ ends in a slash.  I've seen it also at other personal sites.  How are they able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

They use rewrite rules in their .htaccess files, so /iphone/ could be a folder, or it could be a controller/action of their web application.

Check this link for more info:

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/